# How to Know the address of a variable in CUDA?

Tags: cuda

I am doing my project in CUDA. For my project, i am in need of knowing the memory address of where the variables are stored. Is it possible to know the address of the variable, If it is possible, can anyone tell me how to know the address of a variable in CUDA program?

Comment: I have tried of using cudaGetSymbolAddress function where the address is returned as device pointer.

Comment: what is your sm version ?

Comment: I am using Geforce 310 with cuda driver version-5.5 and compute capability-1.2.

Answer (score -2):

When coding cuda you are basically coding c(most of the time at least),

This means that getting the address of a variable:

```
int i = 10;
```

can be retrieved by doing:

```
int *i_ptr = &i;
```

`i_ptr` now contains the address of `i`, this can be done for any data, you do however have to be careful about the host/device setup since the device cannot look up addresses in the host memory space (when zero-copying is not enabled), and the host cannot look up addresses in the device space.

To summarize, your programming C,

Happy Hacking :)